# My react app suddenly missing all dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have been working on a react app for two months.
Suddenly today when I ran 'npm start' it runs basic react app. By basic react app I mean the basic template you get when you create app using 'npx create-react-app', the one with react logo spinning etc.
My index.js file is returned to basic, App.js file as well.
Most dependencies in package.json file are gone, and I had plenty of them, axios, react-redux, redux-thunk, to name a few. Everything is gone.
Most other components are there. The ones that I created during the process.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Any ideas why ?